# Adding extensions to php from a Docker container

Tags: php, docker, curl, gmp, alpine-linux

I'm using Arch Linux os.

I have a container running a php project and I need to have gmp and curl extensions enabled.

My container is based from an Alpine image and I can install the extensions using `docker exec {container-name} apk add php-gmp php-curl`.

Then if I run `docker exec {container-name} php -m` to display my extensions the console prints `gmp` and `curl`. Great this is all good, I also have the extensions enabled in the php.ini file running inside the same container.

But if I go to a controller and return `extension_loaded('gmp')` it prints false!

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you using? mod_php? PHP-FPM? The CLI web server? You may need to restart the webserver / PHP process on the relevant container.

Comment: In that case yeah you probably need to restart the service, though might be best to add the extensions in a Dockerfile and rebuild the image, that way it will be there each time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've done a bit of research to find that I have another container running nginx and so am using php-fpm.

I've now tried rebuilding the nginx container with `docker build` this rebuilt the nginx container...but no difference.

I then found that after installing a package for php-fpm you must do `sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`, which I've now tried from both containers to no avail.

The nginx container has /etc/init.d but no php-fpm executable and the php container has no /etc/init.d directory.

I feel like I'm so close to success I can smell it.

Comment: Dockerfiles apparently have a problem with importing the dependency packages with `RUN apk add`, for example. I'm thinking I get this part working then move on to the Dockerfile problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shout out to [Jon Stirling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling) for his answer.

I needed to re-edit the **Dockerfile** to include the `gmp` and `curl` packages and then also had **Dockerfile** edit the **php.ini** config file to include the `gmp` and `curl` extensions as well.

So:

> RUN apk add --no-cache \
>
> > ...{all my other packages}...
> >
> > php-gpm \
> >
> > php-curl
> >
> > RUN sed -i 's/extension=gmp.*$/extension=gmp/;s/extension=curl.*$/extension=curl/;' /etc/php7/php.ini

The last line uses the terminal tool 'sed -i' to replace any lines that match `extension=gmp` and `extension=curl` and replaces the whole line that they're on.

This basically un-comments them from the **php.ini** file without having to copy a whole new **php.ini** file from the directory.

After rebuilding the whole project using `docker-compose build` then starting everything up again `extension_loaded('gmp')` returned `true`!